# IOS Push Notifications sound not coming

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am working on Ios push notifications where I am able to get Push notifications. But problem is I am not able to get any sound when receiving a Push notification. I have checked my Notification center also and there I have enable sound already. My code is given below, kindly guide me how to fix this issue.

```
    @UIApplicationMain class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
            (granted, error) in
            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
            guard granted else { return }
            self.getNotificationSettings()
        }

        return true
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
    {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    func getNotificationSettings() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
            print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
            guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else {
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            })
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        createInstallationOnParse(deviceTokenData: deviceToken)
    }


    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register: \(error)")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate , UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
```

as when you do

```
 UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
```

the delegate isn't retained so , `willPresent` method isn't called , so do

```
 UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

---

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications() 

    return true

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
    print("tokenMyDevice : \(token)")

} 

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {


    print("get push :  " , userInfo ,  UIApplication.shared.applicationState )

}
```

---

Read the fail error here

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("failed to register for remote notifications with with error: \(error)")
}
```

---

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

     completionHandler([.sound,.alert])


    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, in my above code snippet I have already put the line which you suggest me. Can you please check and guide me.

Comment: can you please check my updated answer. Still it is not working.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, still sound is not coming.

Comment: you removed `willPresent` ?

Comment: Can you please check it. Still the sound not coming.. But I am able to get Push Notifications in background & foreground.

Comment: make sure push notification is enabled in your capabilities and entitlements file added to your project , and you configure the token correctly in server

Comment: Both are enabled. That is why I am getting Push Notifications. Only sound is not coming in Push Notifications. That is my problem

Comment: device is silent ? do you set sound for the sended notification ? also don't see **registerForRemoteNotifications** in didfinish

Comment: Yes Device is not silent and sound is Default.

Comment: I didn't get registerForRemoteNotifications in didfinish?

Comment: Where to put extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate ? I mean outside of class brackets or inside?