# iOS Push Notification No default Sound swift 5

Tags: swift

I am working on FCM push notifications where I am able to get Push notifications. But problem is I am not able to get any sound when receiving a FCM Push notification. I have checked my Notification center also and there I have enable sound already. My code is given below, kindly guide me how to fix this issue.

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      
       FirebaseApp.configure()
       Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
       
              if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
           // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
           UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
           let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]

           UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
               options: authOptions,
               completionHandler: {_, _ in })
           // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
           UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
           Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
           let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
           notificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
       } else {
           let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
               UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
           application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
           application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
       }
       
       application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
      
       
       return true
   }


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                               willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                               withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    completionHandler([.sound,.alert])

   }
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54482859/ios-push-notifications-sound-not-coming

Comment: @Dalijeet- i try that too.but no result